# anchor tag custom link button background color change conditionally using css class

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am looking for help, I and written some code for css custom button. and using html anchor tag i am invoking css class (:after , :before).but now I JUST want to change background color of this button using another subclass (:disable)
with condition (if string1 == string2 else default). I think ng-disable does not work along with anchor.

html :

`<a class=" crumbs" href="url">Start</a>`

looking something like :
`<a class="crumbs "  a-disabled="{$strng == $strng2 }" href="url">Start</a>`

and upon success of a-disabled condition it should add a.disabled css class to change background color.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-class for this

```
<a class="crumbs " ng-class="{disabled: string1==string2}" href="url">Start</a>
```

See this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)